# Split by a colon that is not led by an asterisk

Tags: objective-c, regex

I'm a beginner to using Regular Expressions, and I'm looking for a pattern that will split a string by a colon that is not preceded by an asterisk.

I found the following pattern which I thought would work, but doesn't.

```
[^:]+\\*:[^:]+
```

(the `\*` is escaped to work in a Objective-C compiler)

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [negative look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<![*]):
```

This regex matches a `colon(:)` that is not preceded by -> `(?<!..)` a `*` -> `[*]`. Using `*` inside a character class, it looses it's meaning, and just matches a `*`.

Answer (score 0):

A single character which is not an asterisk can be expressed like so: `[^*]`. This puts the asterisk into a character class, where it has no special meaning. The caret immediately after the opening brace negates the character class.

Matching a colon which is preceded by anything not an asterisk can then be written simply as `[^*]:`

To get just the colon for purposes of location, put it into a group by itself: `[^*](:)`